# How to resolve the error related postman given below?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

in[image]How to resolve the error given below?

**FileEntity.java** -Java Pojo class carrying data.

```
@Entity
//table name
@Table(name = "file_details")
public class FileEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private String file_id;

private String user_id;

private String file_name;

public String getFile_id() {
    return file_id;
}

public void setFile_id(String file_id) {
    this.file_id = file_id;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getFile_name() {
    return file_name;
}

public void setFile_name(String file_name) {
    this.file_name = file_name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "File_Details [file_id=" + file_id + ", user_id=" + user_id + ", file_name=" + file_name + "]";
}
}
```

**FileRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface FileRepository extends JpaRepository<FileEntity, String> {

 @Query("select file from file_details file where file.user_id = ?1")
 List<FileEntity> findByUserId(String user_id);
}
```

**MainController.java**
The controller which controls the flow of data

```
//Post request to upload file to the google drive and get id of the file uploaded to the drive
@PostMapping(value = "/upload/{user_id}")
public ResponseEntity<FileEntity> uploadFIle(FileEntity fileEntity,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@PathVariable String user_id){
   //here I am getting field which I have stored on google drive
    String fileId = fileManager.uploadFile(file);
   //Here I am passing field id and userid which I want to store in db
    FileEntity updated = fileManager.createOrUpdateFile(fileEntity,fileId,user_id);
return new ResponseEntity<FileEntity>(updated, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**FileManager.java** - service class which contains various functions.

```
public class FileManager {

@Autowired
private GoogleDriveManager googleDriveManager;

@Autowired
FileRepository fileRepository;
```

**uploadFile function**

```
 public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        //String folderId = getFolderId(filePath);
        if (file != null) {
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            //fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
            fileMetadata.setName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            File uploadFile = googleDriveManager.getInstance()
                    .files()
                    .create(fileMetadata, new InputStreamContent(
                            file.getContentType(),
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()))
                    )
                    .setFields("id").execute();
            String fileId = uploadFile.getId();
            return fileId;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Error: "+e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**createOrUpdateFile** function to store data to db

```
public FileEntity createOrUpdateFile(FileEntity fileEntity, String fileId, String user_id) {
    Optional<FileEntity> employee = fileRepository.findById(fileEntity.getFile_id());
    
    if(employee.isPresent()) 
    {
        FileEntity newEntity = employee.get();
        newEntity.setFile_id(fileId);
        newEntity.setUser_id(user_id);
        newEntity.setFile_name(fileEntity.getFile_name());

        newEntity = fileRepository.save(newEntity);
         
        return newEntity;
    } else {
        fileEntity = fileRepository.save(fileEntity);
         
        return fileEntity;
    }
}
```

This project is to upload file to the google drive, and to get the id which identifies file stored in the google drive. And also we want to view file uploaded by the each user, So here we are storing file id and user id to the database to view the file.

Comment: The logs should be showing the error in detail. Are you adding the multipart file properly? Also, try some other REST clients apart from Postman.

Comment: @EusufKanchwala But i didnt got any error before i am adding this  line FileEntity updated = fileManager.createOrUpdateFile(fileEntity,fileId,user_id); .

Comment: @EusufKanchwala Worked properly with this @PostMapping(value = "/upload/{user_id}")
 public ResponseEntity<FileEntity> uploadFIle(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@PathVariable String user_id){
  String fileId = fileManager.uploadFile(file);
  ObjectNode jsonObject = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
     
     jsonObject.put("fileId", fileId);
  jsonObject.put("message", "success");
  
  return new ResponseEntity<Object>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: @EusufKanchwala   I think i am getting this error because my logic error.but I am not able to understand what exactly I have to change.

Comment: 404 error means, that your request didn't reach destination, cause endpoint is not found. Verify that in Postman you are using correct url, path, etc.

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov. Url was correct only, I had added a screenshot of postman above now.

Comment: What is the `FileEntity fileEntity` parameter in the `uploadFIle()` endpoint method and how is it supposed to be "injected" there?

Comment: You have missed context path in url may be..

Comment: @JoãoDias I had added FileEntity class above.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not change a thing in my answer below. Have you tried it? If you didn't please do. But coming back to your implementation, how do you expect `FileEntity fileEntity` parameter in the `uploadFIle()` endpoint method to be "injected" there? That simply does not work, see the explanation in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are expecting `FileEntity fileEntity` to be passed in your `uploadFIle()` method in your Controller. But that is not possible, since a `FileEntity` is what you are trying to create and you never add such information in your REST call. Additionally, you are complexifying the method for no reason. It should only call a single method in your `FileManager` class as follows:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/upload/{user_id}")
public ResponseEntity<FileEntity> uploadFIle(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@PathVariable String user_id){
    FileEntity updated = fileManager.uploadFile(file, user_id);
    return new ResponseEntity<FileEntity>(updated, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Your `FileManager.updloadFile()` method should take care of everything: uploading the file to Google Drive and also storing its information in the database. It is this method that actually creates a `FileEntity` object and not the Controller method:

```java
public class FileManager {
    (...)

    public FileEntity uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String user_id) {
       try {
           //String folderId = getFolderId(filePath);
           if (file != null) {
               String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
               File fileMetadata = new File();
               //fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
               fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
               File uploadFile = googleDriveManager.getInstance()
                       .files()
                       .create(fileMetadata, new InputStreamContent(
                               file.getContentType(),
                               new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()))
                       )
                       .setFields("id").execute();
               String fileId = uploadFile.getId();
               return storeNewFileData(fileId, fileName, user_id);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.print("Error: "+e);
       }
       return null;
    }

    private FileEntity storeNewFileData(String fileId, String fileName, String user_id) {
        FileEntity newEntity = new FileEntity();
        newEntity.setFile_id(fileId);
        newEntity.setUser_id(user_id);
        newEntity.setFile_name(fileName);

        return fileRepository.save(newEntity);
    }

    // You could add here another method for the update of an existing file, but trying to joining both in a simple method does not seem right to me and makes the code harder to read

    (...)
}
```